# Help identifying a component in glass housing (looking like a resistor) and markings "PH 41 48"

Tags: components, identification

I have found an electric component and am asking what its name is.

[image: unknown component]

The orange thing is smaller than the a resistor, if that helps...
Thanks all.

**New Info**

The characters written are:
PH
41
48

Comment: Looks like a diode to me.

Comment: Could be a [glass thermistor](https://5.imimg.com/data5/SH/TK/MY-35818124/axial-lead-glass-thermistor-500x500.jpg). If you really need to find out, put a 1k ohm in series and feed 5V to the resistor in series with this unknown object and measure the voltage across it. If you get <1V it be a diode, if you get something larger, it might be a thermistor. Or a [Zener diode](http://robotechshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/diode-1n4148.jpg).

Comment: It has some markings on it (it looks like 2 sets of 2 characters each, perhaps?) - those might help with identification.

Comment: The part number is printed on the part. You've managed to photograph it without showing either side. Redo the photo and crop it this time. The part is < 1% of your photo. Type out the part number if you can read it.

Comment: Get a meter on that thing, put it in diode mode and measure it backwards and forwards, then ohms mode. Report your findings

Comment: Could it be a 1n4148 clone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> PH
>   41
>   48

That marking is the Philips (now Nexperia) version of the 1N4148 diode.

Here is the [Nexperia datasheet link](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/1N4148_1N4448.pdf), where that marking is confirmed:

[image: extract from Nexperia 1N4148 diode datasheet showing package marking]